# Displacement/Pressure Finite Element formulation for Large Deformations (from Bathe)

Tags: finite-element, incompressible

On page 563 of Finite Element Procedures by Klaus-Jürgen Bathe the author states that governing equations of the displacement/pressure finite element formulation for large deformations is given as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^T{\bf K}{\bf U}{\bf U} & {}^T{\bf K}{\bf U}{\bf P}\\
{}^T{\bf K}{\bf P}{\bf U} & {}^T{\bf K}{\bf P}{\bf P}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf \hat u}\\
{\bf \hat p}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf {}^{t + \Delta t} R}\\
{\bf 0}
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
{}^T{\bf F}{\bf U}\\
{}^T{\bf F}{\bf P}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and can be arrived at "by linearization", using

$$
{}^t_0{\bf W} = {}^t_0{\bf \overline W} - \frac{1}{\kappa}({}^t{\bf \overline t} - {}^t{\bf \tilde t})^2
$$

Please refer to [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Publications_Prior_to_1998/A_Finite_Element_Formulation_for_Nonlinear_Incompressible_Elastic_and_Inelastic_Analysis.pdf#page=7) for a complete definition of the terms. I would like to be derive these governing equations but I don't know how to begin the linearization.

Answer (score 1):

We have recently proposed a [mixed u-p formulation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341000436_A_linearised_consistent_mixed_displacement-pressure_formulation_for_hyperelasticity) that results in a global symmetric matrix irrespective of the volumetric energy function (for hyperelasticity).

The paper contains sufficient details on the linearisation (2nd derivative).